# blackberry - add Fields to a Screen

Tags: java, blackberry

I have been testing the Blackberry LabelField, ObjectListField and other input classes.

I would like to add a number of Label fields to the bottom of a BlackBerry screen.

For example, I have an application that gets GPS readings. I would like to append a Label field for each record.

Furthermore I want to display items one at a time over a period of time (eg 5 minutes)
What structure/technique would be best for this?

maybe something like:

```
  for (int count = 1; count <10 ; count++) 
  {
    String LabelField = "labelField" +                
    String.valueOf(count);                                
    LabelField = new LabelField();
    add(LabelField);
  }
```

Comment: How is that supposed to work? Add a String, isn't something missing in that example?

Answer (score 2):

If you just keep adding Fields (such as LabelField) to a VeriticalFieldManager, it will just keep adding them to the bottom of the manager.  Luckily, the standard MainScreen also acts like a VerticalFieldManager - so if you just keep adding new fields to it, they will be appended to the bottom.